# Find the line parallel to $x + y = 1$ and tangent to $x^2 + xy + y^3 = 3$

Tags: calculus

Can someone please help me?

How can I find a line that is parallel to $x + y = 1$ and tangent to $x^2 + xy + y^3 = 3$?
 (at the same time)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: implicit differentiation

$$2x\,dx+y\,dx+x\,dy+3y^2\,dy=0\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+y}{x+3y^2}$$

Now you want points $\,(x_0,y_0)\;$ *on the graph of the function* s.t.

$$-\frac{2x_0+y_0}{x_0+3y_0^2}=-1\;\ldots\ldots$$